# Recursive method to pair all values of an unknown number of arrays and values

Tags: javascript, json

i'm trying to pair all values of an unknown number of arrays and their values.

Below is my JSON:

```
{"AttributeGroups":
[
     {"Name":"Color","Attributes":
        [
         {"Name":"Grey"},
         {"Name":"Blue"},
         {"Name":"Pink",}
        ]
    },
    {"Name":"Size","Attributes":
        [
            {"Name":"XXS"},
            {"Name":"XS"},
            {"Name":"S"},
            {"Name":"M"},
            {"Name":"L"},
            {"Name":"XL"},
            {"Name":"XXL"}
        ]
    },
    {"Name":"Cut","Attributes":
        [
            {"Name":"Diamond"},
            {"Name":"Loose"}
        ],
    }
]}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is effectively:

```
GreyXXSDiamond
GreyXSDiamond
GreySDiamond
...
GreyXXSLoose
GreyXSLoose
...
BlueXXSDiamond
BlueXSDiamond
...
```

I've tried a couple recursive function found on SO, but to no avail.

My failed <s>jQuery</s> javascript is:

```
        if (product.AttributeSet.AttributeGroups.length > 0) {

        var groupIndex = 0;
        for (var g = 0; g < product.AttributeSet.AttributeGroups.length; g++) {
            var group = product.AttributeSet.AttributeGroups[g];

            for (var a = 0; a < group.Attributes.length; a++) {
               var attribute = group.Attributes[a];

                var x = 0;

                var otherAtts = '';
                for (var g2 = 0; g2 < product.AttributeSet.AttributeGroups.length; g2++) {
                    if (g2 > groupIndex) {

                        var group2 = product.AttributeSet.AttributeGroups[g2];

                        for (var a2 = 0; a2 < group2.Attributes.length; a2++) {
                            var attribute2 = group2.Attributes[a2];
                            otherAtts += attribute2.Name;
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(attribute.Name + otherAtts);

            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Obviously the above does not work. Can anyone provide any insight on how to implement a recursive solution?

Comment: don't use loops, use recursive functions

Comment: *"My failed jQuery is..."* That's not jQuery. jQuery is not synonymous with JavaScript. jQuery is just a code library written in JavaScript.

Comment: This doesn't require recursion. *heads off to hack*

Comment: yes, that is not jQuery - I misspoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this iteratively, by appending the contents of every attribute group to the results from the previous step:

```
// go over the previous results, and append the contents of the group to each
function appendAttributes(attributes, accum) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(accum, function(_, it) {
        $.each(attributes, function(_, attr) {
            result.push(it+attr.Name);
        });
    });
    return result;
} 

var result = [""] // starter value
$.each(data.AttributeGroups, function(_, group) {
    result = appendAttributes(group.Attributes, result);
});

console.log(result);
```

jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/inerdial/FdFcB/1/ (results are `console.log`ged)

Answer (score 1):

@Inerdial's code is good, here's another, functional approach:

```
result = obj["AttributeGroups"].reduce(function(r, item) { 
    return item.Attributes.reduce(function(ary, att) {
        return ary.concat(r.map(function(s) { return s + att.Name }))
    }, []);
}, [""])
```